# Send sms in gsm arduino contact from c#

Tags: c#, arduino, gsm

Good Day, I am currently doing a project wherein i am fetching the number that i will send a message from c#, when i manually input the number it will send but, if it is from the c# it wont. This is my arduino code.:

```
boolean stringComplete = false;
String inputString = "";
void loop() 
{

   if(stringComplete)
   { 
     SIM900.print("AT+CMGF=1\r");
     delay(100);
     SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"" +inputString+ "\"");
     delay(100);
     SIM900.println("This message is from HD Robot. Medicine not enough.");
     delay(100);
     SIM900.println((char)26);
     delay(100);
     SIM900.println();
     delay(5000);

     inputString = "";
     stringComplete = false;
   }
}
void serialEvent() {
   while (Serial.available()) {

   char inChar = (char)Serial.read();
   inputString += inChar;

   if (inChar == '\n') {
   stringComplete = true;
   }
  }
}
```

And here is my c# code:

```
  DataTable contact = new DataTable();
  contact = database.getContactInformation();

  foreach (DataRow rows in contact.Rows)
   {
      fam = rows["CPNumber"].ToString();
      added = "+63" + fam;
      serial.Write(added);

    }
```

Comment: Just a point...are you sure want to use println? You might want to control \n manually or \r\n.

Comment: Some informations are missing. Please show us the definition of `inputString`. I guess it's a `char *`?. If so, the `+=` operator is not working. Either way the `+=` operator is not working. If you are using a `char[]` for `inputString` you have to use the indicies to acces the positions in the arrya.

Comment: I used this as a substitute on the number SIM900.println("AT + CMGS = \"+639058689017\""); it sends but if im using that one, it won't